# Отобразить в html картинку путь к которой указан в json

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно отрендерить содержимое json файла в html страницу. С текстовыми полями проблем не возникло. Использовал XMLHttpRequest. Картинку загрузить не получается. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Json

```
[
 {
   "name": "Product",
   "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
   "images":"img/img.jpg"
 }
]
```

js (привел весь свой js)

```
(function () {
var container = document.querySelector(".products-list");
getProduct();
function renderProduct(test) {
    test.forEach(function (product) {
        var element = getElementFromTemplate(product);
        container.appendChild(element);
    });
}

   function getProduct() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'data/test.json');
    xhr.onload = function (evt) {
        var rawData = evt.target.response;
        var loadedProduct = JSON.parse(rawData);
        renderProduct(loadedProduct);
    };
    xhr.send();
}

  function getElementFromTemplate(data) {
    var template = document.querySelector('#test');
    if ('content' in template) {
        var element = template.content.children[0].cloneNode(true);
    } else {
        var element = template.children[0].cloneNode(true);
    }
    element.querySelector('.product-item__title').textContent = data.name;
    element.querySelector('.content').textContent = data.description;

    var titleImages = new Image(); // Здесь пытаюсь вывести картинку
    titleImages.src = data.images;
    element.querySelector('.img-cont').innerHTML = titleImages;
    return element;
}
})();
```

html

```
<li class="product-item">
    <span class="img-cont">

    </span>
    <h2 class="product-item__title"></h2>
    <p class="content"></p>

</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
document.querySelector('.img-cont').innerHTML = '<img src="https://assets.servedby-buysellads.com/p/manage/asset/id/33430" alt="" />';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mp9459mg/